# How to Disable a button using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css

i wanted to disable a button when the page loads depending on the **privilege level** of the user. i already tried this code

```
if($previlage != 2)
{
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('US').setAttribute('disabled');</script>";
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it in the HTML button with an if `<button <?= ($previlage != 2) ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>>`

Comment: Did any error appear in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thy this

```
if($previlage != 2)
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('US').disabled = true;</script>";
```

make sure to print the JS after loading the button in DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any javascript or jquery code:

```
<button <?php echo $privillage != 2 ? "disabled='disabled'" : "" ?>> Button</button>
```